# Access specific elements list

Tags: python, list

For my example, I created the list below that has elements for grocery items and their prices. How would I access the value of a specific item and its cost. For example, I want subtract the value for chicken from another number.

```
ShoppingList = [["Chicken", 10], ["Water", 5], ["Detergent", 8]]
```

Comment: Why are you using a list instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Loop through the list until you find the element whose first element is `Chicken`. Then subtract the second element and break out of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, That is an excellent question. The reason I'm not using a dictionary is because I didn't think of it

Comment: Any time you map names to values that should be the first thing you think of.

Comment: You can convert the list into dictionary and pass the key like this `dict(ShoppingList)['Chicken']`